# Related to JWPlayer and Wowza

Tags: amazon-s3, jwplayer, wowza

I am trying to figure it out is it that I have to use Wowza streamer along with JWPlayer to stream the video or JWPlayer streams video for me.

So i will have JWPlayer java script in my web page with the video URL (video stored on Amazon S3) and when i click play, will it download the video from Amazon S3 locally and play it or will it steam the video URL from it's server located on some remote cloud?

I am not able to find this answer on there web site so posting it here.

Comment: Do you have a sample stream from Wowza? What version of the player are you using, JW5 or JW6?

Comment: Can you share the code of the uploading phase with java?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Amazon S3 url in the javascript for the JWPlayer, it will not play the file since S3 does not support seeking within the file.

Some steps below to get this working (your player can be JWPlayer, OVP or Flowplayer)

There are multiple ways you can play your video off Amazon S3:

1) Player <== Wowza <== Amazon s3
2) Player <== Amazon Cloud front  <== Amazon s3

With 1 you have the option of streaming the file out in RTMP, HLS or MSS or RTSP, with 2 you have RTMP and MSS.

For 1, you will have to set up wowza with the mediacache addon, the configuration instructions are given with the mediacache addon.